# Programming a 2D grid in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

What is the best data structure to use when programming a 2-dimensional grid of tiles in Java? Tiles on the grid should be easily referenced by their location, so that neighbors and paths can be efficiently computed. Should it be a 2D array? An ArrayList? Something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're not worrying about speed or memory too much, you can simply use a 2D array - this should work well enough.

If speed and/or memory are issues for you then this depends on memory usage and the access pattern.

A single dimensional array is the way to go if you need high performance. You compute the proper index as `y * wdt + x`. There are 2 potential problems with this: cache misses and memory usage.

If you know that your access pattern is such that you fetch neighbours of an element most of the time, then mapping a 2D space into a 1D array as described above may cause cache misses - you want the neighbours to be close in memory, and neighbours from 2 different rows are not. You may have to map your 2d tiles in a different order to your 1d array. See [Hilbert curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) for example.

For better memory usage, if you know that most of your tiles are always the same (e.g. always grass), you might want to implement a [sparse array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judy_array) or a [quad tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). Both can be implemented quite efficiently, with cache awareness in mind (the sparse array link is good example for this). Another benefit is that these can be dynamically extended. However, you will always have to pay extra levels of indirection in the end for this to work.

NOTE: Be careful with using generic classes such as `HashMap`s with the key type being some primitive type or a special location class if you're worried about performance - you will either have to allocate an object each time you index the hash map or pay the price of boxing/unboxing. In addition to this, hash maps will not allow you efficient spatial queries (e.g. give me all objects existing in the radius R of a given object - quad trees are better for this).

Comment: +1 for the wide range of alternatives and focus on performance issues.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a fixed dimension for your grid, use a 2D array. If you need the size to be dynamic, use an ArrayList of ArrayLists.

Answer (score 2):

A 2D array seems like a good bet if you plan on inserting stuff into specific locations. As long as its a fixed Size.

Answer (score 2):

The data structure to use really depends on the type of operations you will perform:

In case the number of meaningful positions (nonzero/nondefault) in the grid is rather low (*<< n x m*) it might be more space efficient to use a hashmap, that maps *(x,y)* positions to specific tiles. Also you can iterate over meaningful positions alot more efficiently. In addition you could store references to neighboring tiles to each tile to speed up path/neighborhood traversal.

If your grid is densely filled with "information" you should consider using a 2d array or ArrayList (in case you will at some point have generic types involved as "tile-type", you have to use ArrayLists, since Java does not allow native arrays of generic type).

Answer (score 1):

If you simply need to iterate over the grid and random addressing of cells, then MyCellType[][] should be fine.  This is most efficient in terms of space and (one would expect) time for these use-cases.